# XNA 3D Unable to Position Bounding Sphere

Tags: c#, matrix, 3d, xna, collision-detection

I have a collision method which seems like it would work, and it does, but the bounding sphere is always at 0, 0, 0. How do I fix this?

```
BoundingSphere CreateBoundingSphereForModel(Model model, Matrix worldMatrix)
{
    Matrix[] boneTransforms = new Matrix[this.model.Bones.Count];
    this.model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(boneTransforms);

    BoundingSphere boundingSphere = new BoundingSphere();
    BoundingSphere meshSphere;

    for (int i = 0; i < model.Meshes.Count; i++)
    {
        meshSphere = model.Meshes[i].BoundingSphere.Transform(boneTransforms[i]);
        boundingSphere = BoundingSphere.CreateMerged(boundingSphere, meshSphere);
    }
    BoundingSphereRenderer.Render(boundingSphere.Transform(worldMatrix), GraphicsDevice, view, projection, Color.Green);
    return boundingSphere.Transform(worldMatrix);
}

bool IsCollision2(Model model1, Matrix world1, Model model2, Matrix world2)
{
    BoundingSphere bs1 = CreateBoundingSphereForModel(model1, world1);
    BoundingSphere bs2 = CreateBoundingSphereForModel(model2, world2);

    if (bs1.Intersects(bs2))
        return true;

    return false;
}

private bool checkPlayerCollision(Model model1, Matrix world1)
{
    //Make player location matrix
    Vector3 playloc = new Vector3(X, Y, Z);
    //Make ship1 matrix
    Matrix ship1WorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship1loc) * Matrix.CreateScale(0.1f);
    //Make ship2 matrix
    Matrix ship2WorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship2loc) * Matrix.CreateScale(0.1f);
    //Check for collision with ship1
    if (IsCollision2(model1, world1, model, ship1WorldMatrix)) return true;
    //Check for collision with ship2
    if (IsCollision2(model1, world1, model, ship2WorldMatrix)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved on the Game Development forums. Thanks to Codie Morgan for the answer! https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68207/xna-3d-unable-to-position-bounding-sphere/68300?noredirect=1#comment122391_68300